# Что отвечает за анимацию Item в Terraria?

Tags: c#

создал новый предмет и в SetDefaults закинул строчку:

```
Main.itemFrame[item.type] = 3;
```

сам код выглядит так:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Terraria;
using Terraria.ID;
using Terraria.ModLoader;

namespace Bug_Error.Items
{
    public class Test_Bug : ModItem
    {
        public override void SetStaticDefaults()
        {
            DisplayName.SetDefault("Test_Bug");
            Tooltip.SetDefault("This is a modded sword.");
        }
        public override void SetDefaults()
        {
            Main.itemFrame[item.type] = 3; //Проблемная строка
            item.damage = 50;
            item.melee = true;
            item.width = 64;
            item.height = 64;
            item.useTime = 20;
            item.useAnimation = 20;
            item.useStyle = 1;
            item.knockBack = 6;
            item.value = 10000;
            item.rare = 2;
            item.UseSound = SoundID.Item1;
            item.autoReuse = true;
        }

        public override void AddRecipes()
        {
            ModRecipe recipe = new ModRecipe(mod);
            recipe.AddIngredient(ItemID.DirtBlock, 1);
            recipe.AddTile(TileID.WorkBenches);
            recipe.SetResult(this);
            recipe.AddRecipe();
        }
    }
}
```

Искал во многих источниках и нашел максимум инфу по анимации для NPC и тем, не более. Вдруг кто знает, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Анимация предметов осуществляется путем подключения дополнительной библиотеки `using Terraria.DataStructures;`
После этого создается метод

```cs
public override DrawAnimation GetAnimation()
{
    return new DrawAnimationVertical(20,6);
}
```

Первое значение в `DrawAnimationVertical` - количество тиков на фрейм, второе значение - количество кадров в изображении использующимся для предмета

В более новых версиях, по информации из форума посвященного tModLoader, есть такой код

```cs
public override void FindFrame(int frameHeight)
{
    npc.frameCounter++; // count ingame ticks before next npc frame update
    if (npc.frameCounter >= 8) // if it's time to update npc frame
    {
        npc.frameCounter = 0; // reset ticks counter
        frame++; // move frame
        frame %= 6; // but keep it in range between 0 and 5
        npc.frame.Y = frameHeight * (frame + rageMode ? 6 : 0); // if boss in the second phase, move frame to the second area and apply npc frame
    }
}
```

8 -- interval between frame updates.(интервал между фреймами)
6 -- number of frames for each phase.(число фреймов на каждую фазу)
rageMode -- bool variable to track boss phase. (переменная, для отслеживания фазы босса)
Данный код используется для Глаза-Ктулху, у которого две фазы.
Также необходимо объявить переменную в классе, для работы выше представленного кода `int frame = 0;`

Comment: пишет "не найден метод, пригодный для переопределения" для GetAnimation()

Comment: В официальном мануале нет информации про анимацию, потому добавил код, с форума по tModLoader

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но с NPC у меня проблем не возникало и анимации я добавил, а вот на предмет не получается.